# Allure Report + Video as an attachment/hyperlink using TestNG and Java

Tags: java, testng, allure

How to attach a hyperlink or a video to allure report?

I am able to attach a screenshot to the allure report but how to do attach the video or the hyperlink of the video.

I am generating video from monte media library
I am generating video from selenium grid video node.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach hyperlink just as string Attachment which could be rendered as text or json. Also you can improve testng-adaptor to add hyperlink to the test description on test finish using markdown rendering.

```
public class AllureTestListener implements IResultListener, ISuiteListener  {
...
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        String videoUrl = "http://localhost";
        Description desc = new Description().withType(MARKDOWN);
        desc.setValue("Please find attached video [here](" + videoUrl + ")");
        Allure.LIFECYCLE.fire((TestCaseEvent) context -> 
            context.setDescription(desc)
        );
        fireFinishTest();
    } 
...
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind can I have a  sample code to attach a video

Comment: Thank you. Will look into this.